# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sqlite_db'

Tags: python, flask

I really don't understand how this works. I got the code from the flaskr example. It used to work and now it doesn't.

I am getting the following error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sqlite_db'`

offending line: `top.sqlite_db = sqlite_db`

```
from champNotif_v2 import app
from flask import _app_ctx_stack, g
import sqlite3

def get_db():
    """Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for the
    current application context.
    """
    top = _app_ctx_stack.top
    if not hasattr(top, 'sqlite_db'):
        sqlite_db = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
        sqlite_db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        top.sqlite_db = sqlite_db

    return top.sqlite_db
```

---

`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('info.py')

import champNotif_v2.views
```

---

`info.py`

```
DATABASE = "freeChamp.db"
```

Comment: It appears I have to do app.run and access the db by calling views. I was just trying to run a module through main previously for quick testing. lesson learned.

Comment: Although it *shouldn't* matter, try importing sqlite3 before _app_ctx_stack (all the examples I can find do that).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `top` is `None`, not whatever your expecting it to be. Therefore `_app_ctx_stack.top` must be `None` as that is what `top` is being set to. You need to work out why `_app_ctx_stack.top` is `None` and fix that, or if this is to be expected add a check before using `top` in that way, for example:

```
top = _app_ctx_stack.top
...
if top is not None:
    top.sqlite_db = sqlite_db
```

Comment: I don't understand why it's none.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what `_app_ctx_stack` is either, but clearly sometimes it can be `None` so you need to catch that. This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311974/connect-to-a-database-in-flask-which-approach-is-better might help you use a different method altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at one of the examples in this [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/extensiondev/) you will notice that in the line

```
if not hasattr(top, 'sqlite3_db'):
```

It is asking `sqlite3_db` and not `sqlite_db`,May be that is your problem.

Comment: `top` is `None` so `if not hasattr(top, 'sqlite3_db')` is always `True` regardless of the attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

You need put your code inside the `with app.app_context()` block like this

```
def init_db():
    """Initializes the database."""
    with app.app_context():
        db = get_db()
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()
```