# Flask teardown request in context of blueprint

Tags: python, flask

I would like to access an sqlite3 database from a Flask application (without using Flask-SQLAlchemy, since I require fts4 functionality). I am using Flask blueprints, and I am not sure where to put the following functions (shamelessly copied from a response to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311974/connect-to-a-database-in-flask-which-approach-is-better)):

```
def request_has_connection():
    return hasattr(flask.g, 'dbconn')

def get_request_connection():
    if not request_has_connection():
        flask.g.dbconn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
        # Do something to make this connection transactional.
        # I'm not familiar enough with SQLite to know what that is.
    return flask.g.dbconn

@app.teardown_request
def close_db_connection(ex):
    if request_has_connection():
        conn = get_request_connection()
        # Rollback
        # Alternatively, you could automatically commit if ex is None
        # and rollback otherwise, but I question the wisdom 
        # of automatically committing.
        conn.close()
```

My file structure is:

```
app
├── __init__.py
├── main
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── views.py
├── models.py
├── static
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── index.html
    └── login.html
```

I want the request_has_connection() and get_request_connection() functions accessible from all view functions and maybe from models.py as well. Right now, I'm thinking they all belong in my blueprint **init**.py, which currently contains:

```
from flask import Blueprint
main = Blueprint('main',__name__)
from . import views
```

and that my request teardown function would be registered as

```
@main.teardown_request
def close_db_connection(ex):
    <blah-blah-blah>
```

Is this right?

Comment: This sort of question is easier to address if you try to implement what you have in mind and ask about specific things that are not working or you have trouble following.