# how to use after_request in flask to close database connection and python?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

How to use after_request decorator to close a connection after the request is processed? I use the before_request for opening the connection for each api request as follows:
Using sqlalchemy core 1.0.8 and postgresql 9.5:

```
#engine = create_engine(os.environ.get("DB_URL"))
DB_URL="postgresql://mowner:passwd@localhost/mydb"

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    engine = create_engine(DB_URL, strategy='threadlocal')
    conn = engine.connect()


@app.after_request
def after_request(conn):
     if conn is not None:
         print 'closing connection'
         conn.close()
```

sample api call:

```
@app.route('/api/v1.0/categories', methods=['GET'])
def categories_list():
    '''
    Return categories list
    '''
    if 'id' in session:
        categories_list = []
        s = select([categories])
        rs = conn.execute(s)
        if rs.rowcount > 0:
            for r in rs:
                categories_list.append(dict(r))
            rs.close()
        # print 'this doesnt execute'
        return jsonify({'categories list': categories_list}), 200

    return jsonify({'message': "UNAUTHORIZED"}), 401
```

The views are api calls which only return a list of objects, added, or edit object and a message. How exactly to pass the connection object to the after_request decorator? I couldn't really follow the documentation 
Exact code will help me.

Comment: Using `conn` inside `categories_list ` doesn't throw any error?

Comment: @GarbageCollector there is a before_request, it didn't besides I have used it in __init__.py

Comment: You can use [flask.g](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.g) to create a global database connection object.

Comment: I think I found something here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311974/connect-to-a-database-in-flask-which-approach-is-better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [flask.g](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.g) to refer to create a global db connection object and use it everywhere

```
from flask import Flask, g

#engine = create_engine(os.environ.get("DB_URL"))
DB_URL="postgresql://mowner:passwd@localhost/mydb"

@app.before_request
def before_request():
   engine = create_engine(DB_URL, strategy='threadlocal')
   conn = engine.connect()
   g.db = conn
```

Then use connection in your route like this

```
@app.route('/api/v1.0/categories', methods=['GET'])
def categories_list():
    '''
    Return categories list
    '''
    if 'id' in session:
        categories_list = []
        s = select([categories])
        rs = g.db.execute(s) # change in variable
        if rs.rowcount > 0:
           for r in rs:
             categories_list.append(dict(r))
        rs.close()
        # print 'this doesnt execute'
       return jsonify({'categories list': categories_list}), 200
    return jsonify({'message': "UNAUTHORIZED"}), 401
```

Then finally close it like this:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    if g.db is not None:
        print 'closing connection'
        g.db.close()
     return response
```

Comment: One catch with this is that `g` cannot be used outside of the request context, say if you want to spin up an async thread after returning a response, then the thread can't work with the db this way.